# Zero-padding a string to a finite length

Tags: c, padding, zero-padding

I would like to add a zero padding to a string to make the string a specific final length. In my specific case I want the string to be of length 6 at the end and be padded with 0's before.

```
int val = 5;
int val2 = 12;
char* padded_val = "000005";
char* padded_val2 = "000012";
```

I've seen a lot of answers in C# and not a lot in C, the ones I did see added a padding of a certain length to the start of an int or char but what I want is to add a padding to have a final length of 6.

I'd really appreciate a link if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("%06d", val);
```

The `0` indicates what you are padding with and the `6` shows the length of the integer number.

If you wish to store the result as a string, you can do as following.

```
char padded_val[7] = {0};
sprintf(padded_val, "%06d", val);
```

Comment: Yes, the point was to store the result in a string! Thanks. (Answer will be accepted soon)

Comment: note that this will cause a buffer overflow if `val > 999999` or `val < -99999`  , it would be a good idea to use `snprintf`

Comment: @M.M it's right, sir. Mine is not amiss, but yours is better.